# ddev Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "key"

Tags: drush

I'm trying to run

> `ddev exec drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1`

With MAMP `drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1` works fine.
With ddev I get the error:

```
Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "key".
```

I've tried every possible variation of this command I could think of, also using ddev ssh.
Nothing works.

Am I missing something?
Is this impossible with ddev?

Comment: It's either `ddev exec "drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1"` with the quotes or `ddev drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1` without `exec`. Which version of DDEV? `ddev --version`?

Comment: version is v1.17.7

Comment: If have the same version. `ddev drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1` without `exec` works.

Comment: ddev exec drush "state:set system.maintenance_mode 1"  <br/>
ddev drush "state:set system.maintenance_mode 1"  <br/>
ddev drush state-set "system.maintenance_mode 1"  <br/>
ddev exec drush state-set "system.maintenance_mode 1"  <br/>
ddev exec drush state:set "system.maintenance_mode 1"  <br/>
ddev drush state:set "system.maintenance_mode 1"  <br/>

I could try more versions, but shouldn't this be documented somewhere?
At least, I could not find it...

Comment: I can't edit this comment anymore. Only for 5 minutes while I try to discover why line breaks don't work. Two spaces for a line break don't work here...

Comment: @leymannx  Trying both versions, I get the error: Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "key".